# CSS gradient text

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have a part of a website that involves text with a gradient inside of it. I have tried searching how to do it but nothing is working for me.

What is the efficient way to do this?

```
.gradient-text {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f3ec78, #af4261);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-family: "Archivo Black", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 6em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -0.25em;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with sample HTML and CSS you have tried and describe your challenge with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add gradient text to all h1 tags:

HTML:

```
<h1>Gradient text</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

To add a gradient background, not text:

HTML:

```
<h1>Gradient background</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f3ec78, #af4261);
}
```